# How to use python3 in virtual environment

Tags: python

I want to create virtual environment using python3. But it takes python2 by default. I have both python2 and 3 installed on my machine.

The ouput of when I create the virtual environment is:

`$ virtualenv .env
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2
New python executable in /some/path/.env/bin/python2
Also creating executable in /some/path/.env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.`

I would like to specify which python version to use in the virtualenv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
virtualenv --python=python3.5 myenv
```

Answer (score 2):

When using virtualenv these are the usual steps to follow:

Create the virtualenv using a specific python version of your liking using the `-p` or `--python` arguments

`virtualenv -p /usr/bin/your-python ./path-where-to-create-venv`

Activate the virtualenv, in order to install libraries et cetera

`source ./venv-path/bin/activate`

You can see that you're working from inside the virtualenv, you can deactivate using

`deactivate`